# Cannot create algorithm with name 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1'

Tags: cryptography, single-sign-on, session-cookies, adfs, hmacsha1

I'm getting following error in some severs after user successfully authenticated from ADFS.

```
[ArgumentException: ID6037: Cannot create algorithm with name 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1'.
Parameter name: algorithm]
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Algorithms.NewDefaultEncryption() +170
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.RsaEncryptionCookieTransform.Encode(Byte[] value) +204
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ApplyTransforms(Byte[] cookie, Boolean outbound) +47
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(XmlWriter writer, SecurityToken token) +449      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(SessionSecurityToken sessionToken) +84
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(SessionSecurityToken sessionToken) +123
....
```

Its working fine in our dev / staging servers. But it's not working in some other servers and production server. I'm using following code for DPAPI user session cookie issue.

```
    void OnServiceConfigurationCreated(object sender, ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sessionTransforms = new List<CookieTransform>(new CookieTransform[]{
            new DeflateCookieTransform(),
            new RsaEncryptionCookieTransform(e.ServiceConfiguration.ServiceCertificate),
            new RsaSignatureCookieTransform(e.ServiceConfiguration.ServiceCertificate)
        });
        var readOnlyTransforms = sessionTransforms.AsReadOnly();
        var sessionHandler = new SessionSecurityTokenHandler(readOnlyTransforms);
        e.ServiceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.AddOrReplace(sessionHandler);
    }
```

I have tried to use SHA256 certificate for this and still I got the same error.

Comment: Unfortunately *we* cannot see the configuration differences between the servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many researches one of my friends suggestion worked. I was using following code in Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        //Certificate
        FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfigurationCreated += OnServiceConfigurationCreated;
    }


    void OnServiceConfigurationCreated(object sender, ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sessionTransforms = new List<CookieTransform>(new CookieTransform[]{
            new DeflateCookieTransform(),
            new RsaEncryptionCookieTransform(e.ServiceConfiguration.ServiceCertificate),
            new RsaSignatureCookieTransform(e.ServiceConfiguration.ServiceCertificate)
        });
        var readOnlyTransforms = sessionTransforms.AsReadOnly();
        var sessionHandler = new SessionSecurityTokenHandler(readOnlyTransforms);
        e.ServiceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.AddOrReplace(sessionHandler);
    }
```

Problem was following line,

```
 new RsaEncryptionCookieTransform(e.ServiceConfiguration.ServiceCertificate),
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.rsasha1signaturecookietransform.aspx#Remarks) we can use RsaSignatureCookieTransform instead of this where SHA-256 is not supported. So we used following line instead of RsaSignatureCookieTransform.

```
new RsaSha1SignatureCookieTransform(e.ServiceConfiguration.ServiceCertificate),
```

This solved our issue.